# How to keep the media player keep playing the same sound track and not starting another one in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an action bar icon on the main activity where when you click on it plays a soundtrack and I can pause and play it properly. I call this code below when the action bar play icon is pressed:

```
private void play() {
    if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();//play sound
        play=true;
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        mp.pause();
        play=false;
    }
}
```

onOptionsItemSelected code:

```
if (id == com.app.myapp.R.id.play) {
    play();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

I have another activity that has a home button action icon where when I click it, it takes me back to the main activity and the sound track keeps playing but when I click the play icon again, it plays another instance of the same track which I don't want it to do. I'm use the following code to go back to the main activity:

```
if (id == com.app.myapp.R.id.homebutton) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
}
```

What extra piece of code do I need to do what I want my app to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jaffer

Comment: Use single instance of mediaplayer and have some flags or check the current status of the mediaplayer before starting the playback.

Comment: I am which is what this code is doing if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.start();//play sound
        play=true;
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        mp.pause();
        play=false;
    } but for some reason it still plays another instance

Comment: Is it playing two times or it is just restarting the playback?
From your code I don't think it will start one more instance of playback.

Comment: it's starting two times only when I click the home button

Comment: You are hearing two audio?

Comment: Better approach would be having background service for playback. This is also helpful when your application goes to background you can still play the song.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you post you complete code? I will try to debug myself.

Comment: what is your email? as it doesn't allow me to paste all the code here

Comment: kiran.n.biradar@gmail.com

Comment: ok I sent you the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you launch the main activity from sub activities your main activity is getting created. Since you are creating mediaPlayer instance in onCreate() function new media player instance is created causing two playbacks.

Modify how you launch the main activity like below.

```
if (id == com.app.twelveimams.R.id.homebutton) {
    Log.e("kiran", "clear top from introu");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // Call once you redirect to another activity
```